# How to create an azure function as a listener to a third party api post request that returns event results and make it realtime?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a third party Api that has a post request function which specifies the URL of a listener to which the app will report events of the specified type.

I need to make this real time using a azure function trigger, such that whenever a event occurs the response is received.

1.Should i use normal http trigger or timer trigger?
2.How to create one using python?
Finally, i would like to orchestrate this in an adf pipeline to further interactions with the events response.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event hub trigger which will only be trigger once the event is received.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-java) to deploy event hub trigger function.

You can also deploy the above function in ADF using azure function activity.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) on how run azure function in ADF.